# How to create an Apple Connect API JWT token by ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, apple-sign-in

I have to create an Apple Connect API JWT token by ColdFusion.
I have found out jwt.io library and have used it:

```
variables.jwtTest = new BB.jwtio.jwt();
variables.token = variables.jwtTest.encode({
    'aud': 'appstoreconnect-v1',
    'iss': variables.appleConnectAPISetting.IssuerID,
    'iat': variables.timestampNowUTC,
    'exp': variables.timestampExpUTC
},
variables.appleConnectAPISetting.PrivateKey,
'ES256',
{
    'kid': variables.appleConnectAPISetting.KeyID
});
writeDump(variables.token);
```

But be created token did not working.
I try some code like following:

```
variables.timestampNowUTC = dateDiff("s", CreateDate(1970,1,1), dateConvert('local2Utc', now()));
variables.timestampExpUTC = dateDiff("s", CreateDate(1970,1,1), dateConvert('local2Utc', dateAdd('n', 10, now())));

//generate jwt 
variables.jwt_header = {
    'alg': 'ES256',
    'typ': 'JWT',
    'kid': variables.appleConnectAPISetting.KeyID
};
variables.jwt_header = serializeJSON(variables.jwt_header);
variables.jwt_header = toBase64(variables.jwt_header);

variables.jwt_claim = {
    'aud': 'appstoreconnect-v1',
    'iss': variables.appleConnectAPISetting.IssuerID,
    'iat': variables.timestampNowUTC,
    'exp': variables.timestampExpUTC
};

variables.jwt_claim = serializeJSON(variables.jwt_claim);
variables.jwt_claim = toBase64(variables.jwt_claim);

variables.jwt = variables.jwt_header & '.' & variables.jwt_claim;

//sign jwt
variables.keyText = reReplace( variables.appleConnectAPISetting.PrivateKey, "-----(BEGIN|END)[^\r\n]+", "", "all" );
variables.keyText = trim( variables.keyText );

variables.privateKeySpec = createObject( "java", "java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec" )
    .init(binaryDecode(variables.keyText, "base64"));

variables.privateKey = createObject( "java", "java.security.KeyFactory" )
    .getInstance("EC")
    .generatePrivate(variables.privateKeySpec);

variables.signer = createObject( "java", "java.security.Signature" )
    .getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");

variables.signer.initSign( variables.privateKey );
variables.signer.update( charsetDecode( variables.jwt, "utf-8" ) );
variables.signedBytes = signer.sign();
variables.signedBase64 = toBase64(signedBytes);

variables.token = variables.jwt & '.' & variables.signedBase64;

writeDump(variables.token);
```

I have tried these token to authentic apple connect api, but they did not working.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I used a jwt CFC found here:
https://github.com/jcberquist/jwt-cfml

And the documentation from Apple here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests

This function works for me:

```
<cffunction name="createAPIToken" output="No">
    
    <cfset nonce = createUUID()>

    <!--- 'kid' value is private key ID from App Store Connect --->
    <cfset tokenHeader = {
        "kid":"YOURPRIVATEKEYID"
    }>

    <!--- iss value: issuer ID from the Keys page in App Store Connect --->
    <cfset tokenPayload = {
        "iss":"issuer ID from the Keys page in App Store Connect",
        "iat":now(),
        "exp":dateAdd("n",60,now()),
        "aud":"appstoreconnect-v1",
        "nonce":"#nonce#",
        "bid":"Your app’s bundle ID"
    }>

    <cfset jwt = createobject("component","path.to.jwt").init()>

    <cfset token = jwt.encode(tokenPayload, YourAppStoreConnectPrivateKey, 'ES256',tokenHeader)>

    <cfreturn token>

</cffunction>
```

Comment: I have used this jwt cfc in my code. But be created token cannot authentic apple API. Even if I use your code.

Comment: You may need to double-check the data you get from Apple is correct for your App:

YOURPRIVATEKEYID, 
issuer ID from the Keys page in App Store Connect, 
Your app’s bundle ID, 
YourAppStoreConnectPrivateKey,